Looking for a book I read pre-1990. Possibly called "The Wells of Yutan". A group of people go on a journey up a river
I am trying to find a book I came across when I was in primary/middle school. So it was written before 1990.
I remember that it started with a small group of people. Clans has ravaged a village, a girl was found, it was alluded to that she was damaged from being attacked. They then start on a river trip and one of the group has their hand in the river but remove it because they see a monster or something.
I keep thinking it's called The Wells of Yutan. But I have googled that and nothing similar comes up.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/111467834-the-wells-of-phyre - Mention of clans in the blurb

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, how old was the girl? Was she the hero of the book? Where was it set? What kind of monster was it? Were these people White, African, Russian? Was it aimed at children? How long was the book? What was on the cover? Can you remember any of the character names? Who was the author?

These are all the books on ISFDB starting with "The wells of"

Ancient Dreams, (The Wells of Ythan #1), 1988 by Marc Alexander  (ISFDb).
There appears to be 4 books in this series, this is the first one.
One of the reviews on Goodreads notes:

Krispian, apprentice Toymaker, agrees to go on the search when his village is destroyed and his childhood love is left in a childlike state after the horrers she witnessed.


Yes. The scene with the hand in the river is: As Krispin rowed into a channel there was a sudden startling chorus of protest as a flock of wading birds took to the air with trailing legs; a sandbank seemed to come to shivering life for a moment as freshwater crabs covering it scuttled into the water, and Margan jerked her hand out of the water as she caught sight of a sinuous shape gliding through the water below them.

The girl who is traumatised by the attack is Jennet. She has reverted to childhood and behaves like a young girl even though she is in her late teens.

Are you perhaps thinking of "The Tombs of Atuan" by Ursula Le Guin?
It was published in 1971 so written well before your cut of date of 1990.
It does feature a young girl who has been attacked, here is a summary from wikipedia...

Set in the fictional world of Earthsea, The Tombs of Atuan follows the story of Tenar, a young girl born in the Kargish empire, who is taken while still a child to be the high priestess to the "Nameless Ones" at the Tombs of Atuan. Her existence at the Tombs is a lonely one, deepened by the isolation of being the highest ranking priestess. Her world is disrupted by the arrival of Ged, the protagonist of A Wizard of Earthsea, who seeks to steal the half of a talisman buried in the treasury of the Tombs. Tenar traps him in the labyrinth under the Tombs, but then rebels against her teaching and keeps him alive. Through him she learns more of the outside world, and begins to question her faith in the Nameless Ones and her place at the Tombs.

full entry can be read here...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tombs_of_Atuan
Finally, I would say "The Tombs of Atuan" is a very close match to "The Wells of Yutan"

Tenar is not injured by an attack or rescued from a village, and there is no trip that involves a river, so I don't think this is a particularly close match for the question. (She is given up by her mother to become a priestess, if I recall correctly.)

ooooh my badness.... seems I got this one wrong... what's the correct etiquette? should i delete my answer? please advise. thank you.

Yes, I would go ahead and delete.

@skyjack In your place I would not delete my answer. It's a genuine attempt at an answer and deserves the upvotes is has attracted. Its a wrong answer, but few of us have never posted a wrong answer on this site :-)
